# Is there a way to store both Image and string variables in one array? (Unity)

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am making a 3D game in unity where player can interact with images and notes (approximately 3-4 paragraphs).

I created the canvas, when player interacts with the notes on the ground, the menu(canvas) pops up.

I wonder, is there any way to store string variables with Image gameObjects in the same array?
Also, i'm going to use these images on the canvas, so should i create as an Image or as a Sprite ?

Comment: The simplest way would be to create a class containing a string and an image, and store that class in your collection (Array, List, or whatever).

Comment: in c#, there is this  "object[] arr" in which we can store different kinds of variables (int, string, etc.) but as far as i understand, this is not a part of Unity, c#?

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure Unity hasn't somehow removed System.Object from C# :)

Comment: @runoraca the question would be .. what do you need it for? What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: You could also use tuples private (string yourString, Image yourImage)[] yourArray;

Comment: @derHugo player roams through the map and he will find some notes and images, each image or note will lead him to the next location on the map. I made a menu where player can see each note or image (after he finds it, of course) and he can go to the next or previous one if he wants. That's why i thought i needed an array  for player to wander through the notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want them to be UI components, you should create Image components.
2. I suppose you can achieve this by defining your list to be of the two objects common ancestor; `Object`:

```
var list = new List<object>();

list.Add("Hello");
list.Add(5);
list.Add(MyImage);

foreach (object obj in list) 
{
    if (obj is string) 
    {
        Debug.Log(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is ofcourse that this will not be very usefull ... you can do it ofcourse but you would have to parse the element to the specific type when you need it. a `myImageReference.ToString` usually just returns the same as `myImageReference.gameObject.name` (see [`Object.ToString`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.ToString.html)) .. if something is already `is string` then why use `ToString` at all?

Comment: it worked!!  All this time, i tried to initialize the array like declaring a local variable (inside the class but outside of any function), should've done that inside a function. And when i used object[] arr, both variables were assigned into that array. Thank you so much! @Fredrik

Comment: @runoraca well the problem with an `object[]` is simply that the size is fixed and you cannot add elements afterwards (at least not that simple). A `List<object>` is dynamic and grows with the elements you add

Comment: @derHugo, that was not a recommendation - more of a quick way on how to distinguish between the different types in conditional statements. Just wanted something to do with strings if the object was a string, but yeah, in retrospect ToString is quite stupid since it's not something you'd do on a string, hehe.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a common base type from which both inherit. If both things you want to store are e.g. of type `MonoBehaviour` it would make a lot of sense to use this as a base type instead of `object`.

```
public List<MonoBehaviour> List = new List<MonoBehaviour>();
```

That would at least provide you with all functionality that `MonoBehaviour`/`Component` implements. It sounds e.g. like are later interrested in `.transform.position`.

If you are speaking a about UI stuff like [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) and [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) you can even use [`UI.MaskableGraphic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.MaskableGraphic.html) as common type

```
public List<MaskableGraphic> List = new List<MaskableGraphic>();
```

which provides even more UI related properties like e.g. [`color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-color.html) or [`canvas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic-canvas.html).